# How to modify column data-type while column is in used

Tags: oracle, function, plsql

I have problem while I use SELECT query. Unfortunettly, the `ID` is store as `VARCHAR` which is big mistake and right now I have problem in following function

```
FUNCTION GET_SUB_PROJECTS(p_currentUserId IN VARCHAR,p_projectId IN INT)
    RETURN SYS_REFCURSOR IS 
    rc  SYS_REFCURSOR;
    -- getSubProject
BEGIN
OPEN rc FOR
   SELECT
         p.*,
         a.number_ AS activityNumber,
         a.description AS activityDescription
   FROM
         projects p
   LEFT JOIN
         project_users_schedule_dates pusd
   ON
         pusd.ProjectID = p.ProjectID AND pusd.UserID = p_currentUserId
   LEFT JOIN
        activities a
   ON
        a.id = p.activity
   LEFT JOIN 
       responsible_persons rp
   ON 
       rp.ProjectID = p.ProjectID AND rp.UserID = p_currentUserId
   LEFT JOIN 
       users u
   ON 
      u.UserID = p_currentUserId
   WHERE
     (u.User_roleID = 1 AND
     p.CustomName LIKE CONCAT((SELECT CustomName FROM projects pr WHERE pr.ProjectID = p_projectId), '%') AND p.ProjectID <> p_projectId)
     OR 
   ((
      (p.Responsible_person_id = p_currentUserId OR p.Delivery_contact = p_currentUserId OR rp.UserID = p_currentUserId OR (pusd.UserID = p_currentUserId AND SYSTIMESTAMP BETWEEN TO_DATE(pusd.StartDate,'YYYY-MM-DD') AND TO_DATE(pusd.EndDate,'YYYY-MM-DD') + INTERVAL '1' DAY AND
       SYSTIMESTAMP BETWEEN TO_DATE(p.StartDate,'YYYY-MM-DD') AND TO_DATE(p.EndDate,'YYYY-MM-DD') + INTERVAL '1' DAY))
    )
     AND
         p.CustomName LIKE CONCAT((SELECT CustomName FROM projects pr WHERE pr.ProjectID = p_projectId), '%') AND p.ProjectID <> p_projectId)
         ORDER BY p.CustomName;      
RETURN rc;
END GET_SUB_PROJECTS;
```

When I call function it needs to return data, but it doesn't. Somehow, here  `p.Responsible_person_id` and `p.Delivery_contact` needs to be `NUMBER` but somehow it is VARCHAR
When I call function I use

```
SELECT PROJECT_PACKAGE.GET_SUB_PROJECTS('199',141) FROM DUAL
```

I found one solution to modify but It throw me error like

```
Error report -
ORA-01439: column to be modified must be empty to change datatype
01439. 00000 -  "column to be modified must be empty to change datatype"
```

What to do in this situation ? What is the best method to solve this issue ?

Comment: just recreate the table by using CTAS statement : `CREATE TABLE t2 AS SELECT TO_NUMBER(ID) AS ID, <other cols> FROM t`, then `RENAME TABLE t2 TO t`, if you sure `ID` column contains numeric values at all.

Comment: Sorry, I don't understand what you mean. Can you please describe better. Tnx

Comment: What you want is to change the data type of ID column, don't you? This suggested way, you can change to numeric data type without getting `ORA-01439` error. Btw, replace the renaming syntax to `RENAME t2 TO t`

Comment: Yes, changing from VARCHAR to NUMBER

Comment: @BarbarosÖzhan Can you please post answer base on my question. So Responsible_person_Id needs to be number(10,0) and Delivery_contact also. I would be very thankfull.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can [change the data type of a column online](https://asktom.oracle.com/pls/apex/f?p=100:11:0::::P11_QUESTION_ID:9532881300346956686) using `dbms_redefinition`

```
create table t (
  c1 varchar2(10)
    primary key
);

create table t_new (
  c1 number(10, 0)
    primary key
);

insert into t values ( '1.0000' );
commit;

begin 
  dbms_redefinition.start_redef_table ( 
    user, 't', 't_new', 
    col_mapping => 'to_number ( c1 ) c1', 
    options_flag => dbms_redefinition.cons_use_rowid 
  );
end;
/
exec dbms_redefinition.sync_interim_table ( user, 't', 't_new' );
exec dbms_redefinition.finish_redef_table ( user, 't', 't_new' );

desc t

Name   Null?      Type         
C1     NOT NULL   NUMBER(10)

select * from t;

C1   
    1
```

There are also options to copy constraints, triggers, indexes, etc. automatically in this process.